# Sum of ranks using one sided communication but there is nothing being loaded into the target

Tags: python-3.x, mpi, mpi4py

I am aiming to create create a sum of ranks in a ring similar to a allreduce program but using one-sided communication.
For example, if there four processes in this system. The output would be:

```
PE0:    Sum = 6
PE2:    Sum = 6
PE3:    Sum = 6
PE1:    Sum = 6
```

However, with my current solution with one-sided communication, all the sums are 0.
My code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np

rcv_buf = np.empty((), dtype=np.intc) # uninitialized 0 dimensional integer array
status = MPI.Status()

comm_world = MPI.COMM_WORLD
my_rank = comm_world.Get_rank()
size = comm_world.Get_size()

right = (my_rank+1)      % size;
left  = (my_rank-1+size) % size;

snd_buf = np.array(my_rank, dtype=np.intc) # 0 dimensional integer array with 1 element initialized with the value of my_rank
sum = 0
copy = 0

# create a window
win = MPI.Win.Create(snd_buf, 1, MPI.INFO_NULL, comm=comm_world)

# we need a master process 

# sync remote get call
for i in range(size):
    win.Fence(0)
    win.Get(snd_buf, left, copy)
    win.Fence(0)
    
    sum += copy

win.Free()


print(f"PE{my_rank}:\tSum = {copy}")
```

I'm not sure how to check that the Get call is working properly and if it is, is there any other way to load and store.

Comment: Please don’t use fence in a loop. That’s basically a barrier. This code is going to perform horribly.

Answer (score 2):

I was using the win.Get call incorrectly. In the [documentation](https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/mpi4py.MPI.Win.html#mpi4py.MPI.Win.Get), the first parameter of the Get call is specified as **origin (BufSpec)** which I mistook for the origin value that was in the window which was snd_buf but it should be the buffer where you would want your answer to be stored. I also had to include a Put call to send the value of the rank to the next process. This makes the final code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np

rcv_buf = np.empty((), dtype=np.intc) # uninitialized 0 dimensional integer array
status = MPI.Status()

comm_world = MPI.COMM_WORLD
my_rank = comm_world.Get_rank()
size = comm_world.Get_size()

right = (my_rank+1)      % size;
left  = (my_rank-1+size) % size;

snd_buf = np.array(my_rank, dtype=np.intc) # 0 dimensional integer array with 1 element initialized with the value of my_rank
sum = 0

# create a window
win = MPI.Win.Create(snd_buf, 1, MPI.INFO_NULL, comm=comm_world)


# sync remote get call
for i in range(size):
    win.Fence(0)
    win.Put(snd_buf, left)
    win.Fence(0)
    win.Get(rcv_buf, right)
    win.Fence(0)
    sum += rcv_buf


print(f"PE{my_rank}:\tSum = {sum}")


win.Free()
```